# How To Improve PageLoad Speed of website?

Tags: pagespeed, render-blocking

I have some question related to Page load speed. I am testing websites using gtmetrix.com. When Location is selected as India, It shows F grade and suggest to eliminate render-blocking elements(which is main css files.). For other locations it is showing fine grades and no render-blocking elements. Any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thank you so much.

Comment: are you using some css frameworks

Comment: bootstrap only.......nothing else

Comment: well the CSS is +20 kb and the JS for it is also +20 kb

Comment: But why problem is with india location only?

Comment: there is no issue with js......as they as added at the end of files

Comment: depending where your server is or if you are using an CDN there can be some delay